# How to understand whether a column is signed or unsigned from metadata?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, metadata

I am fetching the metadata of a database schema. I need to find out if a column is of unsigned or signed datatype. How do I find that out from the resultSet which gets the metadata. Which column will give me information regarding that? My question is how to grab whether the column is signed or unsigned from the java code? What is the column label that provides this information?

Comment: It may help to know which database engine you're talking about - for instance (as far as I'm aware) MS-SQL and PostgreSQL don't even support unsigned columns.

Comment: I am using MySql. When I try to insert it directly from the database, it inserts with a warning but on doing the same from java code its throwing data out of range exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** 
From java resultset you can get if the column is signed or unsigned. Try below code as an example:

```
ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from tableName where 1<0");//just making sure no row is retrieved as we dont need any here..
ResultSetMetaData rsmd=res.getMetaData();
boolean isColumnOneSigned= rsmd.isSigned(1);
```

`isSigned(int columnNumber)`: Indicates whether values in the designated column are signed numbers.
You can find more about `ResultSetMetaData` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html). It is very useful class.

*For doing same at databsae level*:-

For MySQL Attributes are stored in COLUMN_TYPE in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

```
mysql> show columns from ttypes;
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cid           | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You have to parse out the contents of Type and find unsigned, or not unsigned in thereIt doesn't put anything in for signed columns.
You can have slect query like

```
select COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_TYPE from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='ttypes' and COLUMN_TYPE LIKE '%unsigned%'
```

Comment: My question is how to grab whether the column is signed or unsigned from the java code? What is the column label that provides this information?

Comment: @Poulami check my updated answer to grab whether the column is signed or unsigned from the java code..